# Bash iterate on pairs of files

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I have a directory with a bunch of files with names like `a04x.txt`, each with a corresponding `b04y.txt` file. I need to be able to run some commands on each pair of files and produce an additional file `c04z.txt` for each pair.

The actual numbers on the files are rather large and pretty sparse, so simply iterating over all numbers from 1 to 99 or something like that won't work.

Currently I use the following to handle the task, but seems like a common enough task that there ought to be a shorter/better way to do it:

```
for num in ./a*x.txt
do
  num="${num##*/a}"
  num="${num%x.txt}"

  my_command a${num}x.txt b${num}y.txt c${num}z.txt
done
```

Ideally I would also like to be warned when there are `a${num}x.txt` or `b${num}y.txt` files that don't have a matching file with the same number. I'd also like an easy way to be able to just pipe the sets of files to `xargs` or `parallel` so I can have it process multiple sets of files simultaneously.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Gather all `a*x.txt` and `b*y.txt` in an array, extract the numbers from the filenames, select only the duplicate numbers with `uniq -d`  then pipe the result to `xargs` or `parallel`, e.g. `myfiles=(a*x.txt b*y.txt); printf %s\\n "${myfiles[@]//[^0-9]/}" | sort | uniq -d | parallel cmd a{}x.txt b{}y.txt c{}z.txt`

Comment: @don_crissti, you may as well [post that as an answer](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3927/135943).

Comment: @Wildcard - I know that thread over on the meta :) - however, the question here is not clear as far as I am concerned. OP says _"I would also like to be warned..."_ but doesn't explain what should the script do if there are unpaired files ? Should it warn and skip or should it warn but still run `my_command` (there's a possibility that `my_command` is smart and still runs fine even if some files don't exist - we don't know that...) ? So yeah, there are a couple of things to clarify here. But anyway, if anyone wants to turn my comments into answers, they are welcome to do so, anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One approach would be to do

   ```
   for afile in a*x.txt
   do
       bfile=${afile/a/b}; bfile=${bfile/x.txt/y.txt}
       cfile=${afile/a/c}; cfile=${cfile/x.txt/z.txt}

       my_command "$afile" "$bfile" "$cfile"
   done
   ```

   although I guess that isn’t a big improvement, and it could fail
   in a pathological case like a filename of `afoox.txtbarx.txt`. 
   Also, note that this is specifically a bash feature;
   it might not work in other POSIX-compliant shells
   (unlike `##` and `%`, which are specified by POSIX).
2. It’s a simple matter to say

   ```
       if [ -f "$bfile" ]
       then
           my_command "$afile" "$bfile" "$cfile"
       else
           echo Error
       fi
   ```

   to catch `a` file outliers
   (e.g., `a17x.txt` with no corresponding `b17y.txt`).
3. If you put

   ```
   for afile               # with no list, defaults to "$@"; i.e., the script’s arguments
   do
       bfile=${afile/a/b}; bfile=${bfile/x.txt/y.txt}
       cfile=${afile/a/c}; cfile=${cfile/x.txt/z.txt}

       if [ -f "$bfile" ]
       then
           my_command "$afile" "$bfile" "$cfile"
       else
           echo Error
       fi
   done
   ```

   into a script, then you can run that script
   with a list of `anumx.txt` filenames as arguments,
   and it will process them. 
   You can then run that script through `xargs` or `parallel`.
4. Checking for `b` file outliers (e.g., `b42y.txt`
   with no corresponding `a42x.txt`) as part of the above process
   is not straightforward, but it is easy to do a separate loop:

   ```
   for bfile in b*y.txt
   do
       afile=${bfile/b/a}; afile=${afile/y.txt/x.txt}
       if [ ! -f "$afile" ]
       then
           echo Error
       fi
   done
   ```

Comment: If you're using globs why not just specify what you want?  `for afile in a[0-9][0-9]x.txt`

Comment: There is some ambiguity about what the OP wants.  [The first version of the question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/33e34a8b-fb35-4c21-94fd-73cabc91efe5) says "The actual numbers on the files are sparse, may be quite large, and in a few cases are not just numeric", so it would seem to be inappropriate to assume that the filenames are all `a`, followed by a two-digit number, followed by `x.txt`.  P.S. Note also that even the current version of the question talks about using `a*x.txt`; if you want to criticize the OP's approach, perhaps you should do it in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 3):

GNU parallel has a way to do this, and runs the commands in parallel as a bonus:

```
$ parallel my_command {} \
                      {= s/a([0-9]+)x.txt/b\1y.txt/ =} \
                      {= s/a([0-9]+)x.txt/c\1z.txt/ =} \
           ::: a*x.txt
```

Those substitutions are perl code. The line breaks are just for readability -- this is a one-liner.